# How to use two many to many associations to retrieve all associations in a single SQL select statment?

Tags: sql, database, group-by, mariadb, left-join

I have a books table that has a many-to-many association with a genre table and an authors table. The aim is to pull out all relevent information about a book in a single select statment.

I am using MariaDB 10.11 and the fiddle is in 10.9

Below is the code to create and fill the tables with example data, I have also linked to a dbfiddle

```
CREATE TABLE book (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, title varchar(30));
CREATE TABLE author_example (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE genre (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, genre varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE associate_book_genre (
    genre_id int NOT NULL,
    book_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_book_genre PRIMARY KEY (book_id, genre_id)
  );
CREATE TABLE associate_book_author (
    author_id int NOT NULL,
    book_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_book_genre PRIMARY KEY (book_id, author_id)
    );

INSERT INTO genre (genre) VALUES ("travel"),("philosophy"),("nonfiction");
INSERT INTO author_example (name) VALUES ("Paul Tillich"),("Douglas Adams"),("Mark Carardine");
INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES ("The Courage to Be"), ("Last Chance to See"),("Beowulf"),("Debate between bird and fish");
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/74kXDrRM

My aim is to retrieve this table:

| Book title | Authors | Genres |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Beowulf | null | null |
| Last Chance to See | Douglas Adams & Mark Carardine | travel, nonfiction |
| The Courage to Be | Paul Tillich | philosophy |
| Debate between bird and fish | null | null |

The closest I have come is with

```
SELECT b.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR " & ") as author, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(g.genre SEPARATOR ", ") as genre FROM book b 
left join associate_book_author aba on b.id = aba.book_id 
left join author_example a on aba.author_id=a.id 
left join associate_book_genre abg on b.id = abg.book_id 
left join genre g on abg.genre_id =g.id
  group by g.id;
```

| Book title | Authors | Genres |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Beowulf | null | null |
| Last Chance to See | Douglas Adams & Mark Carardine | travel, travel |
| The Courage to Be | Paul Tillich | philosophy |
| Last Chance to See | Douglas Adams & Mark Carardine | nonfiction, nonfiction |

However I am missing "Debate between bird and fish" since the genre is null for both "Debate between bird and fish" and "Beowulf" and "Last Chances to See" is listed twice and the genres are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should individually aggregate the authors and genres:

```
with a as (
 select aa.book_id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR " & ") as Authors
 from associate_book_author aa
 join author_example a on a.id = aa.author_id
 group by aa.book_id
), g as (
 select ag.book_id, GROUP_CONCAT(g.genre SEPARATOR ", ") as Genres
 from associate_book_genre ag
 join genre g on g.id = ag.genre_id
 group by ag.book_id
)
select b.title, a.Authors, g.Genres
from book b
left join a on a.book_id = b.id
left join g on g.book_id = b.id
order by b.title;
```

Amended [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ugng_-Rf)

Comment: Are there any preformance considerations using mulitple selects, if there thousands of books and authors?

Comment: There are no *multiple* selects per-se, the tables are only queried once, the table expressions are not executed individually but are expanded into a single query at run-time; performance tuning would be a completely separate issue but this will be more performant than your original query since it results in less rows being joined to aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the way you do grouping and made result DISTINCT(unique)
Rather than having it like `group by g.id`
I did it this way:
`GROUP BY b.id, b.title`
Try to run this query:
https://dbfiddle.uk/WwUjVeFo

```
SELECT b.title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.name SEPARATOR ' & ') as author,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.genre SEPARATOR ', ') as genre
FROM book b 
LEFT JOIN associate_book_author aba ON b.id = aba.book_id 
LEFT JOIN author_example a ON aba.author_id = a.id 
LEFT JOIN associate_book_genre abg ON b.id = abg.book_id 
LEFT JOIN genre g ON abg.genre_id = g.id
GROUP BY b.id, b.title
ORDER BY b.title;
```

[image]